# How to fix water damage to wooden table

Tags: wood, staining, wood-repair, water-protection

I have a wooden table, which I accidentally spilled water onto yesterday. I thought it would simply dry, but a couple of hours later I noticed that the water had pooled on the wood and the surface under the pool appeared discolored.

I dried it off and noticed that the gray discoloration was coming off, so I scrubbed all of the gray off, and afterward the color looked consistent. Unfortunately, a few hours later I found that the area under the pools now looks completely different from the rest of the table.

My guess is that I accidentally removed the stain from the wood. I know nothing about this topic though, so I wanted to ask the experts:

What do you think happened here?
How can I fix it?[image]

A picture of the current state of the table is attached.

Comment: Cross-posted to [diy.se]: http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/80134/22

Comment: Looks like that you have to remove the coating by sanding the surface and then apply the new one in several passes with light sanding between each pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What do you think happened here?

It looks like the water either got under the finish and caused it to bubble up/peel or the water partially dissolved the finish, which you then scrubbed off by accident.

> How can I fix it?

If it's finished the shellac, you might be able to apply some new shellac and buff it into the existing finish.

Otherwise, if it's a film-type finish like polyurethane varnish, you're pretty much limited to removing the old finish and doing it over.

---

You've got some good answers on the [cross-post in DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80134/how-to-fix-water-damage-to-wooden-table) too.